# homepage is not loaded after clicking on login button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After clicking on login button I am getting the error in console as :

```
Login.js:28
Uncaught TypeError: loginSubmit is not a function
```

Login Form.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Login from './Login'
import Home from './Home'

function LoginForm() {
const [formLogin, setFormLogin] = useState(false)

    const loginPage = () => {
        setFormLogin(true)
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {!formLogin ? <Login loginSubmit={loginPage} /> : <Home />}
            </div>
    
        </>
    )

}
export default LoginForm
```

Login.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './Home'

function Login({loginSubmit}) {
const nav = useNavigate()

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: ''
    })
    
    const [error, setError] = useState({})
    const [dataCorrect, setDataCorrect] = useState(false)
    
    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setError(LoginValidation(values))
        setDataCorrect(true)
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (Object.keys(error).length === 0 && dataCorrect) {
            loginSubmit(true)
        } 
    }, [error])
    
    const LoginValidation = (values) => {
    
        let errors = {}
    
        if (!values.username) {
            errors.username = "Username is required"
        } else if (!values.username.length < 4 && values.username.length > 6) {
            errors.username = "Username length should be between 4-6"
        }
        if (!values.password) {
            errors.password = "Password is required"
        } else if (!values.password.length < 5 && values.password.length > 10) {
            errors.password = "Password length should be btw 5-10"
        }
    
        return errors
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            <center>
                <h1>Login Page</h1>
                {/* <form className='w-50 p-3'  onClick={() => nav('/home')} > */}
                <form className='w-50 p-3'>
                    <div className='mt-3' >
                        <div className="form-floating mb-5">
                            <input type="text" value={values.username} onChange={changeHandler} name='username' className="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                            <label htmlFor="floatingInput">Username</label>
                            {error.username && <p>{error.username}</p>}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="password" name='password' value={values.password} onChange={changeHandler} className="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password" />
                            <label htmlFor="floatingPassword">Password</label>
                            {error.password && <p>{error.password}</p>}
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div>
                        {/* <button className='btn btn-primary mt-3' type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>Login</button> */}
                        <button className='btn btn-primary mt-3' type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit} >Login</button>
                        <button className='btn btn-info mt-3' onClick={() => nav('/signup')}>Register</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </center>
        </>
    )

}
export default Login
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>Welcome to Home Page</div>
    )
}
export default Home
```

I want home page to be loaded after clicking on login button

Comment: It works fine for me, with React 18.0.0: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-leaf-zvwi2i
What version of React are you using?